# Find out the nearest bigger multiple of (n) PHP

Tags: php, logic

I have a requirement where users are forced to choose the multiple of (n) quantity of a product.

The (n) value is set with each product that can be any number.

customer can only purchase the quantity of product in the multiple of (n) quantity set with product.

Suppose if (n) is 5 and user entered quantity as `4` and says Add to Cart. I have to add quantity of that product as `5` automatically.

and if user entered `6` as quantity then I have to add the `10` quantity of that product.

How I go about that?

I am not getting what logic should be applied here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$entered_quantity = 6;
$suppose_n = 5;

$quantity = ceil($entered_quantity / $suppose_n) * $suppose_n;

echo $quantity;
```

prints 10

Answer (score 3):

that's not php specific;
what you wonna do is to compute.

ceiling(q / n) * n

where q is the user's quantity,
n is the multiplicity

Answer (score 2):

You could try getting the remainder of the number when dividing by the given `n`

e.g.:

```
$n = 5;
$amount = 6; // This would be the input, so replace the 6 with a $_POST/$_GET/etc.
$batches = floor($amount / $n);
$rest = $amount % $n;
if ($rest > 0) {
    $batches += 1;
    // You could give the user feedback here that they didn't put in a full multiple of $n
}
// $batches now contains the right amount of batches, so to get the total:
$total = $batches * $n;
```

Ofcourse this can be condensed a lot, but this might give a better overview of what happens :).

Answer (score 1):

Try the below function.

```
function getNextMultipleOfFive($n) {
    $tmp=explode('.',($n/5));
    if($tmp[1]) {
        return ($tmp[0]+1)*5;
    }
    return $tmp[0]*5;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With a do...while loop:

```
$q = 6; // quantity by user input
$n = 5; // per purchace amount

$i = 0;
if ($q > 0)
{
    do
    {
        $i += $n;
    }
    while ($i <= $q);
}
echo $i; // 10
```

**Note:** not very effective if `$q` >> `$n`

Comment: not a good answer... (that's the kind of "algorithm" which leads to very poor performance. Just image, what happens if n is 5 and q is 100000)

Comment: It is still a solution, but not for every occasion. Read the note.

Comment: @phant0m It's absolutely not "just because it works". For smaller values, its a fine and easily understandable algorithm. It's the developer who decides to use a more efficient method or not. This does not make my solution bad. I also added a note, to point this out.

Comment: I didn't say it's bad, I just consider it overly lengthy, that's all. "It's the developer who decides to use a more efficient method or not. " True, but it doesn't mean we have to agree with his choice ;)

Comment: admitted: it might be acceptable, if q is in the [0..2]*n range (roughly) AND your machine has slow division/multiplication AND you do not pay a big penalty for branches. This might be the case for some slow embedded CPUs (and for machines of the 80's)